# Normal mismatch for one-sided manifold

Tags: ios, opengl-es, 3d, lighting

Recently I am reading a book named *iPhone 3D Programming*. Following its example I found a very confusing problem that my code have "lighting misplace"( or maybe it have a formal name) with "klein bottle".

[image: klein bottle]

Left is correct lighting(from the book's source code).
Right is my version. 
Here is difference between the example and mine.

```
diff --git a/Classes/ApplicationEngine.cpp b/Classes/ApplicationEngine.cpp
index c3ddd05..68f8b36 100644
--- a/Classes/ApplicationEngine.cpp
+++ b/Classes/ApplicationEngine.cpp
@@ -11,8 +11,6 @@
 #include <algorithm>

 using namespace std;
-namespace ParametricViewer {
-  

 static const int Surface_Count = 6;
 static const int Button_Count = Surface_Count - 1;
@@ -54,7 +52,7 @@ private:
   Animation _animation;
 };

-IApplicationEngine* CreateApplicationEngine(IRenderingEngine* renderingEngine) {
+IApplicationEngine* createApplicationEngine(IRenderingEngine* renderingEngine) {
   return new ApplicationEngine(renderingEngine);
 }

@@ -211,4 +209,3 @@ int ApplicationEngine::mapToButton(ivec2 touchpint) const {
   return buttonIndex;
 }

-}
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/Classes/GLView.mm b/Classes/GLView.mm
index 0eeedf6..966041b 100644
--- a/Classes/GLView.mm
+++ b/Classes/GLView.mm
@@ -35,10 +35,10 @@ const BOOL ForceES1 = YES;
             m_renderingEngine = SolidES1::createRenderingEngine();
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Using OpenGL ES 2.0");
-            m_renderingEngine = SolidES2::createRenderingEngine();
+            m_renderingEngine = ES2::createRenderingEngine();
         }

-        m_applicationEngine = ParametricViewer::CreateApplicationEngine(m_renderingEngine);
+        m_applicationEngine = createApplicationEngine(m_renderingEngine);

         [m_context
             renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER
diff --git a/Classes/Interfaces.hpp b/Classes/Interfaces.hpp
index 1f9b129..6bbf0d0 100644
--- a/Classes/Interfaces.hpp
+++ b/Classes/Interfaces.hpp
@@ -58,9 +58,7 @@ namespace SolidES1 {
   IRenderingEngine* createRenderingEngine();
 }

-namespace SolidES2 {
+namespace ES2 {
   IRenderingEngine* createRenderingEngine();
 }
-
-namespace ParametricViewer { IApplicationEngine* CreateApplicationEngine(IRenderingEngine*); }
 #endif
diff --git a/Classes/ParametricEquations.hpp b/Classes/ParametricEquations.hpp
index f06a0a3..ec2942a 100644
--- a/Classes/ParametricEquations.hpp
+++ b/Classes/ParametricEquations.hpp
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@ class Cone : public ParametricSurface {
 public:
   Cone(float height, float radius) : _height(height), _radius(radius)
   {
-    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(20, 20), vec2(TwoPi, 1), vec2(30, 20) };
+    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(20, 20), vec2(TWO_PI, 1), vec2(30, 20) };
     setInterval(interval);
   }
   vec3 evaluate(const vec2& domain) const
@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ class Sphere : public ParametricSurface {
 public:
   Sphere(float radius) : _radius(radius)
   {
-    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(20, 20), vec2(Pi, TwoPi), vec2(20, 35) };
+    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(20, 20), vec2(PI, TWO_PI), vec2(20, 35) };
     setInterval(interval);
   }
   vec3 evaluate(const vec2& domain) const
@@ -45,7 +45,7 @@ public:
   _majorRadius(majorRadius),
   _minorRadius(minorRadius)
   {
-    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(20, 20), vec2(TwoPi, TwoPi), vec2(40, 10) };
+    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(20, 20), vec2(TWO_PI, TWO_PI), vec2(40, 10) };
     setInterval(interval);
   }
   vec3 evaluate(const vec2& domain) const
@@ -67,7 +67,7 @@ class TrefoilKnot : public ParametricSurface {
 public:
   TrefoilKnot(float scale) : _scale(scale)
   {
-    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(60, 15), vec2(TwoPi, TwoPi), vec2(100, 8) };
+    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(60, 15), vec2(TWO_PI, TWO_PI), vec2(100, 8) };
     setInterval(interval);
   }
   vec3 evaluate(const vec2& domain) const
@@ -76,7 +76,7 @@ public:
     const float b = 0.3f;
     const float c = 0.5f;
     const float d = 0.1f;
-    float u = (TwoPi - domain.x) * 2;
+    float u = (TWO_PI - domain.x) * 2;
     float v = domain.y;

     float r = a + b * cos(1.5f * u);
@@ -109,7 +109,7 @@ class MobiusStrip : public ParametricSurface {
 public:
   MobiusStrip(float scale) : _scale(scale)
   {
-    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(40, 20), vec2(TwoPi, TwoPi), vec2(40, 15) };
+    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(40, 20), vec2(TWO_PI, TWO_PI), vec2(40, 15) };
     setInterval(interval);
   }
   vec3 evaluate(const vec2& domain) const
@@ -141,7 +141,7 @@ class KleinBottle : public ParametricSurface {
 public:
   KleinBottle(float scale) : _scale(scale)
   {
-    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(20, 20), vec2(TwoPi, TwoPi), vec2(15, 50) };
+    ParametricInterval interval = { ivec2(20, 20), vec2(TWO_PI, TWO_PI), vec2(15, 50) };
     setInterval(interval);
   }
   vec3 evaluate(const vec2& domain) const
@@ -155,19 +155,19 @@ public:
     float y0  = 8 * sin(u) + (2 * (1 - cos(u) / 2)) * sin(u) * cos(v);

     float x1 = 3 * cos(u) * (1 + sin(u)) +
-    (2 * (1 - cos(u) / 2)) * cos(v + Pi);
+    (2 * (1 - cos(u) / 2)) * cos(v + PI);

     float y1 = 8 * sin(u);

     vec3 range;
-    range.x = u < Pi ? x0 : x1;
-    range.y = u < Pi ? -y0 : -y1;
+    range.x = u < PI ? x0 : x1;
+    range.y = u < PI ? -y0 : -y1;
     range.z = (-2 * (1 - cos(u) / 2)) * sin(v);
     return range * _scale;
   }
-  bool invertNormal(const vec2& domain) const
+  bool InvertNormal(const vec2& domain) const
   {
-    return domain.y > 3 * Pi / 2;
+    return domain.y > 3 * PI / 2;
   }
 private:
   float _scale;
diff --git a/mathLib/Matrix.hpp b/mathLib/Matrix.hpp
index 7b73954..fbbb2d4 100644
--- a/mathLib/Matrix.hpp
+++ b/mathLib/Matrix.hpp
@@ -150,7 +150,7 @@ struct Matrix4 {
   }

   static Matrix4<T> rotate(T degrees) {
-    T radians = degrees * Pi / 180.0f;
+    T radians = degrees * PI / 180.0f;
     T s = std::sin(radians);
     T c = std::cos(radians);

@@ -161,7 +161,7 @@ struct Matrix4 {
   }

   static Matrix4<T> rotate(T degrees, const vec3& axis) {
-    T radians = degrees * Pi / 180.0f;
+    T radians = degrees * PI / 180.0f;
     T s = std::sin(radians);
     T c = std::cos(radians);

diff --git a/mathLib/Quaternion.hpp b/mathLib/Quaternion.hpp
index d1a2a0b..e043760 100644
--- a/mathLib/Quaternion.hpp
+++ b/mathLib/Quaternion.hpp
@@ -53,21 +53,21 @@ inline QuaternionT<T>::QuaternionT(T x, T y, T z, T w) : x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w)
 template <typename T>
 inline QuaternionT<T> QuaternionT<T>:: slerp(T t, const QuaternionT<T>& v1) const {
   const T epsilon = 0.0005f;
-  T DotT = dot(v1);
+  T dotT = dot(v1);

-  if (DotT > 1 - epsilon) {
+  if (dotT > 1 - epsilon) {
     QuaternionT<T> result = v1 + (*this - v1).scaled(t);
     result.normalize();
     return result;
   }

-  if (DotT < 0) DotT = 0;
-  if (DotT > 1) DotT = 1;
+  if (dotT < 0) dotT = 0;
+  if (dotT > 1) dotT = 1;

-  T theta0 = std::acos(DotT);
+  T theta0 = std::acos(dotT);
   T theta = theta0 * t;

-  QuaternionT<T> v2 = (v1 - scaled(DotT));
+  QuaternionT<T> v2 = (v1 - scaled(dotT));
   v2.normalize();

   QuaternionT<T> q = scaled(std::cos(theta)) + v2.scaled(std::sin(theta));
@@ -139,12 +139,12 @@ bool QuaternionT<T>::operator != (const QuaternionT<T>& q) const {
   return !(*this == q);
 }

-// Compute the quaternion that Rotates from a to b, avoiding numerical instability.
+// Compute the quaternion that rotates from a to b, avoiding numerical instability.
 // Taken from "The Shortest Arc Quaternion" by Stan Melax in "Game Programming Gems".
 template <typename T>
 inline QuaternionT<T> QuaternionT<T>::createFromVectors(const Vector3<T>& v0, const Vector3<T>& v1) {
   if (v0 == -v1)
-    return QuaternionT<T>::createFromAxisAngle(vec3(1, 0, 0), Pi);
+    return QuaternionT<T>::createFromAxisAngle(vec3(1, 0, 0), PI);

   Vector3<T> c = v0.cross(v1);
   T d = v0.dot(v1);
@@ -187,7 +187,7 @@ inline void QuaternionT<T>::rotate(const QuaternionT<T>& q2)
   q.y = q1.w * q2.y + q1.y * q2.w + q1.z * q2.x - q1.x * q2.z;
   q.z = q1.w * q2.z + q1.z * q2.w + q1.x * q2.y - q1.y * q2.x;

-  q.Normalize();
+  q.normalize();
   *this = q;
 }

diff --git a/mathLib/Vector.hpp b/mathLib/Vector.hpp
index 781fc64..f43051e 100644
--- a/mathLib/Vector.hpp
+++ b/mathLib/Vector.hpp
@@ -11,15 +11,15 @@

 #include <cmath>

-const float Pi = 4 * std::atan(1.0f);
-const float TwoPi = 2 * Pi;
+const float PI = 4 * std::atan(1.0f);
+const float TWO_PI = 2 * PI;

 template <typename T>
 struct Vector2 {
   Vector2() {}
   Vector2(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {}

-  T Dot(const Vector2& v) const {
+  T dot(const Vector2& v) const {
     return x * v.x + y * v.y;
   }
```

The code almost same except character case. So where am I wrong?
Wrong version using ES1.1
Any suggestion will appreciate.

[Full source code](http://puu.sh/LS1q)

Comment: Wow, never seen a diff file as code sample, but then again, one is more than enough.

Comment: @ChristianRau 'cause I copy the code from book, but result different so I post a diff file to find help.

Comment: Off the top of my head, a good name for your problem might be something like "normal mismatch", or "orientation problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with a Klein bottle is that it is not [orientable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability):  it is a one-sided manifold, so it is impossible to maintain a consistent normal across the entire surface.  No matter how you choose the normals on the mesh, there will always be a line where the normal flips from one side to the other.

It looks like the original (gold) Klein bottle may have been tweaked so the orientation mismatch is just inside the "mouth" of the bottle, hiding the defect rather than fixing it.  Note that, in your (gray) version, you can see the surface just inside the mouth correctly; in the gold bottle, it appears black.  From your diff, I'd guess they might have tweaked the condition in the `InvertNormal()` function.  (No, the diff doesn't show any tweaking -- but it does sound like the logical place to tweak...)

The simplest way to make your Klein bottle seamless is to do a double cover:  each triangle appears twice, facing opposite directions.  This will probably be more complex than simply making your triangles double-sided -- the crux is that each *normal* must also appear twice, pointing in opposite directions.  The most expedient way to do that is to duplicate the vertices, and use a different set of vertices for the opposing (single-sided) triangles.

(I have not looked at your code in detail, but to do the double-cover thing, you'll probably need to extend one of your parametric loops by a factor of 2, and possibly do something like distinguish between positive and negative quaternions.  Don't forget to make the resulting triangles single-sided.)

Comment: I have a `invertNormal()` in super class and subclass using `InvertNormal()`… I first heard that `orientable` can you recommend any book? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a good introductory book on topology.  I recommend you google keywords like "orientable", "manifold", "one-sided", "Klein bottle", and "Mobius strip".